# Complicated pivoting for mysql query considering the data change would occur in future using Mysql as DB

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Please consider the following scenario, below is the DDL and DML statements.

I want to see the output like :

1- for every new **CatName** there should be a new column that should be present
2- **CatName** should be having the data in the **Value** column in it, i dont want to sum it up, just plain values are good.

Using Mysql as database , since it doest have PIVOT function, had spent so much of time but wasted, let me know if this is achievable, the **CatName** is pretty dynamic in nature not a constant values, using case statements equated to the present values in tables will just limit and doest serve if there is more different values in this column in future like **'descp4'** .

I tried generating the sql using 'into' clause  to store the statements generated using GROUP_CONCAT function, but it is not serving the purpose, i appreciate any leads.

```
CREATE TABLE `to_pivot` (
  `Id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID2` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CatName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CatID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ; 

INSERT INTO `to_pivot`
VALUES
(30,
2525,
'Descp1',
NULL,
123),
(29,
2525,
'Descp2',
NULL,
'ABz123'),
(27,
2525,
'Descp3',
NULL,
'SR'),(
25,
2515,
'Descp1',
NULL,
1
),
(32,
2515,
'Descp2',
NULL,
'12DL3');
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit tricky, and you always have to chekc @sql to see, it your query fits.

But it is manageable

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'MAX(IF(CatName = "',
>           CatName,
>           '", `Value`, NULL)) AS "',
>           CatName,'"'
>         )
>   ) INTO @sql
> FROM
>   (SELECT DISTINCT CatName
>     FROM to_pivot) t1;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id2,', @sql, ' FROM to_pivot GROUP BY id2');
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
>  id2 | Descp1 | Descp2 | Descp3
> ---: | :----- | :----- | :-----
> 2525 | 123    | ABz123 | SR    
> 2515 | 1      | 12DL3  | null  
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab07094f90127f0c2f30c58f669cdf4a)*

Comment: Thanks this really helps, much appreciated.